# Using Multiple Chained Selectors

Tags: css

I think there is a way to modify both elements at once? I tried `a b + a c` and such, but nothing seemed to work.

What is the shortest way of typing this?

```
#a #b {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url('xjpg');
    position: absolute;
    margin: 111px 0 0 222px;
}

#a #c {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url('x.jpg');
    position: absolute;
    margin: 111px 0 0 333px;
}
```

Comment: why are you doing #a #b. Assuming there is only one element with ID #b, #b directly should work. Anyways seperate elements with comma like #a #b, #a #c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a comma will allow you to apply properties to more than one chain of selectors, as well as combining the identical properties into one set of properties and overriding the unique styles on the second element.

Most synthesized way is:

```css
#a #b, #a #c {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url('xjpg');
    position: absolute;
    margin: 111px 0 0 222px;
}

#a #c {
    background: url('x.jpg');
    margin: 111px 0 0 333px;
}
```

Make sure the overriding properties are below the original elements properties.

Comment: do you really guys think, that he meant "xjpg" ?

Comment: @WojciechKulik Whether or not that's the case, he still needs the overriding properties for the different margin, unless that's a mistake to.

Comment: Yeap, you're right, but I think that's a mistake also and he was asking only how to "join" these selectors :-). Anyway you're answer is of course correct ;-).

Answer (score 2):

```css
#a #b, #a #c {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url('x.jpg');
    position: absolute;
    margin: 111px 0 0 333px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `comma` lets you specify several selectors for a set of rules.

```css
#a #b,  #a #c {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url('xjpg');
  position: absolute;
  margin: 111px 0 0 222px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#a #b, #a #c {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
}
#a #b {
    background: url('xjpg');
    margin: 111px 0 0 222px;
}
#a #c {
    background: url('x.jpg');
    margin: 111px 0 0 333px;
}
```

or

```css
#a #b, #a #c {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 111px 0 0 222px;
}
#a #b {
    background: url('xjpg');
}
#a #c {
    background: url('x.jpg');
    margin-left: 333px;
}
```